# parse xml node items minus the first

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I am trying to read an external xml file and return a table which I can do. I need however to set a var that can limit the number of results starting with the second node. I can get the number I want I can set that no problem. It is starting with number two thats the problem. Any help would be great.

Here is the parser I am using to write the table. I need help placing the limitation to remove the first node.

```js
document.write("<table id='contenth' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i < number;i++)
  {     
    
  document.write("<td><a target='_blank'href='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'><img src='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'/>"+x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</a></td>");
      
      }

simple xml list
```

```css
<item>
  <title>One</title>
  <description> </description>
  <link></link>
  <image></image>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Two</title>
  <description> </description>
  <link></link>
  <image></image>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Three</title>
  <description> </description>
  <link></link>
  <image></image>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the solution would be to modify the starting value of `i` of your loop, so that the loop starts at `i = 1`. The effect of this would be to skip the first `<item>` in your XML:

```
// Initialize i to 1
for (i=1;i < number;i++)
{     
   ...          
}
```

Comment: ok so I have tried that but it still returns the entire list.

Comment: Can you please include more of your code in the original question?

Comment: Hey, I have two parsers one for vertical one for horizontal I didn't change it in one and checked the other.... Thanks. I just spent several hours beating my head against the wall.... Thanks again